# Can't get motherboard serial number

Tags: java, windows, vbscript

I used the following code for getting the motherboard serial number. But I got the o/p **Result is empty**. What mistake did I make in this code?

```
      File file = File.createTempFile("realhowto",".vbs");
      file.deleteOnExit();
      FileWriter fw = new java.io.FileWriter(file);

      String vbs =
         "Set objWMIService = GetObject(\"winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2\")\n"
        + "Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ \n"
        + "   (\"Select * from Win32_BaseBoard\") \n"
        + "For Each objItem in colItems \n"
        + "    Wscript.Echo objItem.SerialNumber \n"
        + "    exit for  ' do the first cpu only! \n"
        + "Next \n";

      fw.write(vbs);
      fw.close();
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cscript //NoLogo " + file.getPath());
      BufferedReader input =
        new BufferedReader
          (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
      String line;
      while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
         result += line;
      }
       if(result.equalEgnoreCase(" ") {
           System.out.println("Result is empty"); 
       } else {
       System.out.println("Result :>"+result);
      }
      input.close();
    }
```

Comment: I would look for a way that doesn't imply executing VBScript from Java. Do you know COM4J? I'm pretty sure you can use WMI from it.

Comment: @zneak: I didn't used before. Where to get com4j.jar file? Because com4j missing on java.net [site.](http://com4j.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList)

Comment: That's embarassing. Last time I checked the download link worked; I'm sorry, I can't help you.

Comment: Then, try JACOB...http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/

Comment: COM4J Download: http://java.net/projects/com4j/downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that the VBS side of this works fine on my machine; however, the output I got was:

```
MB-1234567890
```

which doesn't seem particularly unique or helpful. Still, if this is what you're after, try the following. Paste the VBS into a .vbs file and run it using `cscript <myfile>.vbs`:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
   ("Select * from Win32_BaseBoard") 
For Each objItem in colItems
    Wscript.Echo objItem.SerialNumber 
    exit for  ' do the first cpu only!
Next
```

If that works, it's the Java that's at fault (and I suspect it's not capturing the process output for some reason). Otherwise, it's the VBS script failing you.

There are some more hints and tips on [this thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/426976/java/java/motherboard-serial-Number-local-system) which might give you some different strategies.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic baseboard get serialnumber");
```

or

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic /node:"HOST" bios get serialnumber");
```

instead of **HOST** , give ur **hostname**, which can be arrived at typing **hostname** in cmd prompt.

Comment: he knows the output is empty. He's looking for a solution.

Comment: @bhakki: try this and let me know,

Comment: I used but i didn't get the result. Is there some other way?

Comment: strange, it works on win7 (ran from java), but it hangs on windows xp, wmic.exe works only thru command prompt)